# Given distance (in meters) what is the angle in geographic reference systems?

Tags: qgis, postgis, distance, spherical-geometry, geodesy

In QGIS and other systems sometimes I have a layer in geographic reference system (typically WGS84, EPSG:4326) and I'd like to calculate a buffer of say 5000m around a point.

So, given a point coordinate (lat/lon) and a distance (in meters), what is the geographic length (angle) in a geographic reference system (for geographic lengths shorter than 180 degrees)?

I'm referring to two implementations (QGIS, postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html ) which offer just that one "buffer radius" parameter.

Remarks: 
 - I'm aware of Cosine Formula and Vincenty (like question 109562) but
   can't resolve the formulas to angle.
 - For the solution I prefer standalone implementations, say in Excel, pl/pgsql, Python or R.

Comment: It changes, based on the direction. This is one of the most commonly asked questions on this site ("direct geodetic problem"). Another is the opposite  (given two points, find bearing and distance, aka "inverse geodetic problem"). Both problems are partial differential equations, only solvable by iterative means (it would have been impressive if you could solve it). A google will find the US Geodetic Survey site with solutions in FORTRAN.

Comment: A circular buffer, when expressed in geographic coordinates, will not be circular (except when its center is one of the poles), so you are asking for something that is mathematically impossible. Your first task, then, is to appreciate what's going on here--which can be accomplished by [reviewing similar threads](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=buffer+distance+geographic)--and your second will be to use that understanding to reformulate your question into something that is answerable.

Comment: whuber: I did not ask for a circular buffer, only for a buffer around a point coordinate and it's parameter. To be specific, I'm referring to two implementations (QGIS, http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html ) which offer just that one parameter. ST_Buffer is described by "Returns a geometry that represents all points whose distance from this Geometry is less than or equal to distance. Calculations are in the Spatial Reference System of this Geometry."

Comment: Exactly, **Calculations are in the Spatial Reference System of this Geometry**, and a Cartesian buffer about a Geographic Coordinate System point isn't worth the bits used to represent it.

Comment: Thanks to all! I found a solution, here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71644/issue-with-buffer-with-projection and here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237356/convert-meters-to-decimal-degrees